# Responsive Skewed Div with background image

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I am attempting to make a page where the screen is split in half with two images from the bottom right corner to the top left corner

[image]
I have done this in CSS using transform: skewY( x amount deg);
I can then change this with javascript when the page loads by calculating the degree needed via trigonometry like so

```
var hlc = document.getElementById('homeleftside');
var hlch = hlc.clientHeight;
var hlcw = hlc.clientWidth;
var hlct = Math.atan(hlch/hlcw);
var hlca = hlct * 180 / Math.PI;
```

and I can do this via javascript every time the page is resized,
but to make this in CSS I have made these classes below and was wondering if there is a better alternative to a responsive degree amount depending on the page size due to editing the pseudo:: after element.

```
.homeleftside::after {
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: skewY(-29deg);
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("graphics/architecture.jpg");
    color: #fff;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.homeleftside {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: skewY(29deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, your only posibility is with a mask-image.

Support is not fully, but it gives an easy way to achieve it.

Note that the direction "top left" (and similars) for a gradient will get you always the diagonal of the element

```css
.test {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, green);
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top right, black 50%, transparent 50%);
    mask-image: linear-gradient(to top right, black 50%, transparent 50%);
}

#test1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

#test2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test1"></div>
<div class="test" id="test2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using `clip-path`

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800) center/cover;
}

body:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/18/800/800) center/cover;
  
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0,0 100%,100% 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,0 100%,100% 100%);
}
```